# Downloading a photo from Facebook for app to use

Tags: facebook, download, photos

We want to be able to download hi-res image from user's Facebook photos to our app.  Currently it seems we can only get low res photo.  What do we need to do to get hi-res photos?

Comment: Log a bug/feature request (which they will probably ignore)

Answer (score 1):

Using FQL you can query the field `src_big` of [photo table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/).

This field, from the official documentation, is:

> The URL to the full-sized version of the photo being queried. The
>   image can have a maximum width or height of 720px, increasing to 960px
>   on 1st March 2012. This URL may be blank

So I think this is the maximun you can get from Facebook API.